# Symfony 4 Secured Area Alert

Tags: php, symfony

I am following this tutorials:-

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

I did registration page but when I am trying access /registration page, Secured Area alert pops out.

Here are my files:

`security.yaml`

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
```

`UserRegistrationController.php`

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserRegistrationController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/registration", name="user_registration")
     */

    public function registerUser(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder) {

        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted and $form->isValid()) {

            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_registration_successful');

        }


        return $this->render(
            'Form/UserRegistration.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );

    }

}
```

`UserType.php`

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

class UserType extends AbstractType {

    public function createForm (FormBuilderInterface $form, array $options) {

        $form
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => array('label', 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label', 'Repeat password')
            ));

    }

    public function configureOptions (OptionsResolver $resolver) {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class
        ));

    }

}
```

`UserRegistrationForm.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}

    <button type="submit">Register!</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Your security.yml file seems incomplete.  Typically you would have a anonymous: ~ in your main firewall.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

Comment: I just took that code from documentation without any modifications.

Comment: Hmmm.  The link I gave you shows differently.  But okay.

Comment: OK I got it now pattern ^/ and http_basic ~ probably means that every page is protected. Thanks for that document.